# Azure AD Graph API - Getting token on iOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, azure, office365

I was already able to access the Graph API using a .NET native client. So this means that the end-user is redirected to a dialog page that requires him to sign-in, and then I get an access Token which allows me to query the Graph.

Meanwhile I'm trying to implement the same on iOS and Android. I do find [information saying that's possible](https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/10/28/android-ios-sdks-tooling/), but I cannot find any sample code or documentation on how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was able to get it working following the below samples:

Android https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android

Objective C https://cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20adal

Answer (score 1):

for acquiring the token, have you checked out the [Azure AD code samples page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-code-samples/) ?  There are iOS and Android samples that demonstrate ADAL/OAuth.

Comment: I was already able to get it working. I will post the code I used. +1 Thanks